# Como insertar un tipo de dato DATE en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema al insertar un dato tipo date a mysql ,melo inserta en lacolumna como 000-00-00
Este es mi Formulario

```
       <div class="form-group">
       <label for="nombre">Fecha recibido</labe> <input type="date" name="fecha_rec" step="1" min="2013-01-01" max="2030-12-31" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">
               </div>
```

Mi sentencia para conectar a la base de datos es la siguiente

```
  <?php

  extract($_POST);  
 $server = "localhost";
              $usuario = "root";
             $contraseña = "";
             $bd = "bdpagina";

 $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd)
or die("error en la conexion");
$sentencia = "UPDATE contribuyente SET estado = '$estado', comentario = '$comentario', servicio = '$servicio' , fecha_rec ='$fecharec'WHERE contribuyente. id = '$id'";
//la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
$resent=mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
if ($resent==null) {
    echo "Error de procesamieno no se han actuaizado los datos";
    echo '<script>alert("ERROR EN PROCESAMIENTO NO SE ACTUALIZARON LOS DATOS")</script> ';
            echo "<script>location.href='usuario.php'</script>";
}else {


    echo "<script>location.href='usuario.php'</script>";

}
 ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como has declarado la columna de fecha en MySql?

Comment: donde tienes la variable $fecharec definida?

Answer (score 0):

en mysql para insertar una fecha y que la reconozca como tal necesitas usar al insertar un dato (o modificarlo) una función: `STR_TO_DATE('".$fecharec."','%Y-%m-%d')` para el formato que parece que tienes en la tabla, pero ojo, tienes que pasar la fecha en php al mismo formato antes.